# Why my menu bar is not displaying in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

My android studio is not showing the main menu bar where File,Code,Build... options remain.For this I can not open a new project or build an apk.I have to close android studio and then again open it and then I click on Create New Project.Please help me bringing back the menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally hide your main menu bar, double tap on Shift key on keyboard, then select 'Actions' and type 'Main menu'. Click on 'Main menu' that appears in list, you will then see the Main menu in a popup window. Choose View > Appearance > Main menu.